# Examples of well written modules

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, development, best-practice

Can anyone point me in the direction (github or magento connect) of any well written modules in terms of code/architecture and not functionality?

Preferably also using unit tests or magespec.

It seems there is a sea of poorly coded modules out there and i am looking for some solid examples.

Also to note that i am aware of the judge app but im more interested in other developers actual knowledge on this.

Comment: Concerning extensions the best thing you can do is look at how core extensions are build. The best way of working in a framework (in my opinion) is "copying" techniques, coding standards and structure and making it your own.

Comment: I would normally agree with you but in Magento i think this approach will only get you so far.  The core code is inconsistent, Module developers need to think about different things than core developer such as looking for nice extension points (observers over rewrites etc) and also there are no tests to look at

Comment: @ToonVanDooren, this could be easily an answer and not a comment.

Comment: Core modules infrequently use rewrites, however, unless you have access to Enterprise Edition.

Comment: @philwinkle : Thats exactly what i mean, these things need to be considered from community module developers not core developers

Comment: @MartyWallace I do agree with you to some extend but you have to start somewhere, when you create a new product type for example, it would be useless to start googling or creating it from scratch instead of looking at and using code from the core.

Comment: Lesti::FPC https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc is one of the best examples I have come across.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te be a little bit self-advertising. We organize a few magento hackathons a year and have great developers who are building modules on this events. A few implement tests, most of them are coded by three, four or more people which peer review the code. Just have a look here:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/

https://github.com/firegento/

The colleagues from UK are doing the same, but I don't know how they code:

https://github.com/MageHack

Comment: Descent examples indeed :)